# Why is my Web API routing not working?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-routing, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following code in my we api:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {


        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //Set default content to json
        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
              name: "DefaultApi2",
              routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
          );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Here is the conreoller and actionmethod I am trying to connect to:

```
  [Authorize]
public class DeviceConnectionController : ApiController
{        
    [HttpGet]
    public string Status(int deviceId)
    {
        string stats = "1234:";
        stats += FSK_APNLink.ConnectionStatus.Connected.ToString();
        return stats;
    }
}
```

Now the following get request gives me a 404:

```
http://localhost:50000/api/deviceconnection/status/45
```

however if I remove the parameter from the action method the following executes correctly:

```
http://localhost:50000/api/deviceconnection/status
```

Comment: Change the parameter in the controller action to be id, instead of deviceId

Comment: Are you sure it executes "correctly"? A non-nullable int gets set to `null` because it's optional and not set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an optional parameter called id which is matched by the route against the list of method parameters. The only method parameter is called `deviceId`, hence it won't have any value. You either need to rename the parameter in the method signature or in the route template.